# Is there anyway to use github / gitlab for downloading the docker image?

Tags: docker, github, gitlab, bitbucket

Since Docker Hub only allows 1 private repo, I wonder if there is any way to use Github or Gitlab, etc., to download the images? for instance:

```
FROM git@github.com/username/repo
...
...
...
```

Comment: GitHub certainly offers a container registry: https://github.blog/2020-09-01-introducing-github-container-registry/

Comment: You mention Gitlab which is a hosted solution, right? So if you have access to a machine to run Gitlab on, you can easily run a registry on it as well.

Comment: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/10/30/mitigating-the-impact-of-docker-hub-pull-requests-limits/

Comment: I know you've asked about solutions in github and gitlab but I would like to recommend AWS ECR, you only pay for bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy with an account on [gitlab.com](http://gitlab.com). GitLab provides a [Docker registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/index.html) linked to projects and you can have unlimited private projects:

- Create a project `my-docker-project`
- Go to *Package and Registries > Container registries*, you should see a few commands to access your registry
- Connect your machine to this registry using a command like:

  ```
  # Will prompt for login/pass
  docker login registry.gitlab.com
  ```

  - You'll need an [access token or deploy token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/#authenticate-with-the-container-registry) with `read_registry` and `write_registry` scopes. You can generate one via your profile *Preferences > Access token*. Login is the token name and password the secret token provided.
- You can now push Docker images with commands such as:

  ```
  # Push an image 
  docker push registry.gitlab.com/YourUsernameOrGroup/my-docker-project

  # Push an image on a sub-path
  docker push registry.gitlab.com/YourUsernameOrGroup/my-docker-project/myimage
  ```

You can then use the image in a Dockerfile by referencing its URL such as:

```
FROM registry.gitlab.com/YourUsernameOrGroup/my-docker-project

# ...
```

Of course the machine from which you build must be authenticated on related GitLab registry using `docker login` command above (or the project must be public)

Comment: Greate answer, one question how can I include the image from another image... like after we pushed how can I use it?

Comment: Thanks :) Sure, I edited with an example.

Answer (score 0):

both have excellent package registry services

For GitHub [**GPR**](https://github.com/features/packages)
For GitLab [**GCR**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/index.html)

Both have excellent features like **use it directly from Dockerfile** as you want for example.

I have a [public example, you can check it in Github](https://github.com/irvv17/deployment-nodeapp-azure) with node.js which uses GPR to store the build image/package.